# JavaFX refresh TableView thread

Tags: java, javafx

I wish to implement a thread that runs the `displayQueue` method in `QueueTabPageController`every couple of seconds so that a table view is updated automatically on a JavaFX GUI.  Currently it is updated manually by pressing the refresh button in the GUI but this is not ideal.  I have tried various methods using some examples on here but cant seem to get it running correctly.  I am new to threads by the way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class QueueTabPageController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  private TableView<Patient> tableView;

  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Patient, String> firstNameColumn;

  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Patient, String> lastNameColumn;

  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Patient, String> timeEnteredColumn;

  @FXML
  private TableColumn<Patient, String> triageAssessmentColumn;

  @FXML
  private QueueTabPageController queueTabPageController;

  private ObservableList<Patient> tableData;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    assert tableView != null : "fx:id=\"tableView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLQueueTabPage.fxml'";

    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("firstName"));
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("lastName"));
    timeEnteredColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("time"));
    triageAssessmentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("triage"));

    // display the current queue to screen when opening page each time
    displayQueue(Queue.queue);

  }

  /**
   * @param event
   * @throws IOException
   */
  @FXML
  private void btnRefreshQueueClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    displayQueue(Queue.queue);
  }

  /**
   * @param queue
   */
  public void displayQueue(LinkedList<Patient> queue) {
    tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(queue);
    tableView.setItems(tableData);
    tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
    tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

thanks,
K

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep 5 secs
            Platform.runLater(() -> {   // Ensure data is updated on JavaFX thread 
                displayQueue(Queue.queue);
            });
        }
    }); 
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
```

This will start a thread that calls displayQueue(Queue.queue) every 5 seconds. Since displayQueue(...) calls tableView.setItems(...), it must be called on the JavaFX Application Thread, thus the requirement to use Platform.runLater().

t.setDaemon(true); will make sure the thread does not prevent the JVM from terminating when all other threads have finished. There are probably better ways to handle thread shutdown...