# How to show changes from a list from a background thread in a JavaFX table?

Tags: multithreading, javafx-8, interactive-brokers

I have a background thread which updates a list with incoming buy sell orders, prices etc. I get the data from my broker asynchronously. It’s important that the updates in the list happens in the background thread sequentially.

I want to display the mainPortfolioList in my javafx table without the risk of a “Not on FX application thread IllegalStateException”. The nearest solution I found was [JavaFX refresh TableView thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883781/javafx-refresh-tableview-thread). But this will not work if the list is in another thread, as I understand it.

I’m quite new in java and tried to solve my problem with an addlistener. I made a simplified example to show what I want and what I’ve done so far.

How can I display updates from my mainPortfolioList in the JavaFX table?

PortfolioController

```
import application.Test;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

public class PortfolioController {

    @FXML private Button btnTest;

    @FXML private TableView<Portfolio> tblPortfolio;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Portfolio, String> colSymbol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Portfolio, Number> colQuantity;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Portfolio, Number> colPrice;

    private ObservableList<Portfolio> fxPortfolioList;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        tblPortfolio.setEditable(true);

        colSymbol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().colSymbolProperty());
        colQuantity.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().colQuantityProperty());
        colPrice.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().colPriceProperty());

        colSymbol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        colQuantity.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Portfolio, Number>forTableColumn(
                new NumberStringConverter("#,##0.00")));
        colQuantity.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            int newValue = event.getNewValue().intValue();
            event.getRowValue().setColQuantity(newValue);});
        colPrice.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Portfolio, Number>forTableColumn(
                new NumberStringConverter("#,##0.00")));

        fxPortfolioList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tblPortfolio.setItems(fxPortfolioList);

        Test.mainPortfolioList.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Portfolio> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        for (Portfolio asset : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                            fxPortfolioList.add(asset);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        for (Portfolio asset : c.getRemoved()) {
                            fxPortfolioList.remove(asset);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                            fxPortfolioList.set(i, c.getList().get(i));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void btnTestClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.dataStream(this);
    }
}
```

Portfolio

```
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Portfolio {
    private final StringProperty colSymbol;
    private final IntegerProperty colQuantity;
    private final DoubleProperty colPrice;

    public Portfolio(String symbol, int quantity, double price) {
        this.colSymbol = new SimpleStringProperty(symbol);
        this.colQuantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.colPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);    
    }

    // extractor
    public static Callback<Portfolio, Observable[]> extractor() {
        return (Portfolio p) -> new Observable[] {
            p.colSymbolProperty(),
            p.colQuantityProperty(),
            p.colPriceProperty(),
        };
    }

    // property 
    public StringProperty colSymbolProperty() {
        return colSymbol;
    }

    public IntegerProperty colQuantityProperty() {
        return colQuantity;
    }

    public DoubleProperty colPriceProperty() {
        return colPrice;
    }

    // getter
    public String getColSymbol() {
        return colSymbol.get();
    }

    public int getColQuantity() {
        return colQuantity.get();
    }

    public double getColPrice() {
        return colPrice.get();
    }

    // setter
    public void setColSymbol(String newValue) {
        colSymbol.set(newValue);
    }

    public void setColQuantity(int newValue) {
        colQuantity.set(newValue);
    }

    public void setColPrice(double newValue) {
        colPrice.set(newValue);
    }
}
```

Test simulation

```
import controller.portfolio.Portfolio;
import controller.portfolio.PortfolioController;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Test {

    public static ObservableList<Portfolio> mainPortfolioList =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(Portfolio.extractor()); 

    public void dataStream(PortfolioController portfolioController) {

        // Need to be sequentially
        // The task only simulates simplified operations
        Runnable task = () -> {

            // add stock 
            mainPortfolioList.add(new Portfolio("AAPL", 13, 153.03));
            mainPortfolioList.add(new Portfolio("MSFT", 31, 67.51));

            // Change the quantity
            for (Portfolio asset : mainPortfolioList) {
                if (asset.getColSymbol().equals("AAPL")) {
                    asset.setColQuantity(55);
                }
            }

            // run price updates
            for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < mainPortfolioList.size(); m++) {
                    double random = Math.random() * 50 + 1;
                    String symbol = mainPortfolioList.get(m).getColSymbol();
                    setTickPrice(symbol, 4, random);
                    randomSleep();
                }
            }

            // remove stock
            for (Portfolio asset : mainPortfolioList) {
                if (asset.getColSymbol().equals("AAPL")) {
                    mainPortfolioList.remove(asset);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(task, "Simulation");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    public void setTickPrice(String symbol, int tickType, double price) {

        for (Portfolio asset : mainPortfolioList) {
            if (asset.getColSymbol().equals(symbol)) {
                switch(tickType){
                    case 4: // Last Price
                        asset.setColPrice(price);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void randomSleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random() * 300));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Portfolio.fxml"));  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.portfolio.PortfolioController">
   <top>
   </top>
   <center>
      <TableView fx:id="tblPortfolio" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colSymbol" maxWidth="80.0" minWidth="60.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Symbol" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colQuantity" maxWidth="60.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Quantity" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colPrice" maxWidth="69.0" minWidth="49.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Price" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </center>
   <bottom>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnTest" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnTestClicked" text="Test">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything coming from the reader thread(assuming IB) that will change something on the screen has to be wrapped in `Platform.runLater`.

eg.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> asset.setColPrice(price));
```

The same for all other calls, like add remove etc.

What would be easier is if in the wrapper for `updatePortfolio` you just wrap a new call to your data model updater with `Platform.runLater`.

```
//in wrapper implementation, this call happens on EReader thread.
void updatePortfolio(Contract contract, int position, double marketPrice, double marketValue,
        double averageCost, double unrealizedPNL, double realizedPNL, String accountName){
    //this moves it to FXApplication thread.
    Platform.runLater(() -> 
        updateMyPortfolio(contract, position, marketPrice));//etc.. more flds 
}
```

That way you can use all the new data in the scene with no worries.

Comment: You’re right with Interactive Brokers. I hoped to avoid your first solution. The second one is quite interesting. I will try that later:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with each wrapper method but there's 2 things to consider.  `Platform.runLater` does all the processing on the GUI thread, so if it's lengthy, the GUI thread becomes unresponsive.  So, only do the minimal amount.  However, lengthy processing on the reader thread runs the risk of blocking the socket eventually.  This is not usually a problem on modern hardware.  It's up to you to decide how much to do on each thread, balancing those needs or figure out if you need another calculation thread in extreme circumstances.